# Did a Rebuild all on project, now get error mentioning MSACAL.DLL

Tags: vb.net

I recently inherited a VB project for some maintenance. I've been making changes and testing in VS2008 using F5. It's been going well.

I did a rebuild all and now it won't run.  It displays a dialog saying something like "MSACAL.dll or some of its dependencies are missing." There are a number of INTEROP.....dll files in ..\obj (I didn't look in ..\bin and am home for the weekend) but none in ..\obj\Debug.

Anyone have a quick answer as to what Rebuild All would have screwed up?

Not only am I not a VB programmer (I do C#), but I have no experience with interops.

Thanks lots.

Jerry

Answer (score 0):

Since you did a rebuild all, it could have also done a rebuild of tests and installs I would start there first.